# Xcode console stopped displaying print statements (Kony)

Tags: xcode, temenos-quantum

I use Kony visualiser platform to build mobile apps. On build, it runs the iOs application through Xcode. I used to see the print statements given in the application code in the Xcode console. Recently, I don't see any application logs in the console. Please suggest if there is some option accidentally switched off from me.

Comment: Make sure you are running in debug mode and not in release mode. In release mode Kony.print will not print anything

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you're building with the debug option. Release mode builds won't print debug statements.